# Should this object be disposed? Code analysis oversight?

Tags: c#, memory-management, asp.net-web-api

In my C# WebAPI code I'm creating a `UnityDependencyResolver`. Code analysis tells me I should dispose the object when losing scope but in fact that object is assigned to `configuration.DependencyResolver`.

Here the code (there is a warning suppress right now to "address" the issue)

```
   [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2000:Dispose objects before losing scope", Justification = "See REV-649")]
    private static void WebApiSetup(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        using (var configuration = new HttpConfiguration())
        {
            // start unity
            var container = UnityConfig.Container;

            // var resolver = new UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(container);
            var resolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);

            configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new AllExceptionsLogger());
            configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new UnhandledExceptionHandler());

            // TODO - remove this for production code (DS)
            configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

            // Remove the XML formatter in particular. After this configuration the only
            // available formatter is JSON, this means that whatever the accept header
            // JSON will be returned.
            configuration.Formatters.Clear();
            configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

            var jsonSerializerSettings = configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;

            // timestamps format
            jsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffzzz";

            // json lowerCamelCase on
            jsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

            // Handle enums as strings
            jsonSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());

            configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
            configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

            // Todo: Add this back in to enable authorisation
            // configuration.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
            app.UseWebApi(configuration);
        }
    }
```

Moreover, Klocwork indicates that there is an invalid cast going on there.

Shall I follow the hint or it's an oversight of code analysis?

Comment: There are quite a few lines in between the creation of the object and assignment to `DependencyResolver`. And none of those intervening lines seem to have any dependencies on `resolver`. So, does anything change if you move object creation down and inline with the property assignment?

Comment: looks like it's solved. Please have an answer here and I'll accept it